# How to write and append to an Excel file using excel package in Flutter?

Tags: excel, flutter, dart, xlsx

My biggest issue right now is that I every time I save the excel file, the program will create and download an entirely new excel file. I don't want that. I want it to write and save everything into the same excel file.

Sample Code:

```
import "package:excel/excel.dart";

var file = "../assets/test.xlsx"; // My Excel File

ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(file);
dynamic bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
Excel excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);
Sheet sheet1 = excel["Sheet1"];

List<String?> itemList = <String?>["A", "B", "C", null]; // What I want to write to the excel file
sheet1.appendRow(itemList);


String outputFile = "../assets/test.xlsx";
List<int>? fileBytes = excel.save();

if (fileBytes != null) {
  File(join(outputFile))
    ..createSync(recursive: true)
    ..writeAsBytesSync(fileBytes);
}  // This is where the problem arises
```

It basically download a new file with the information in it. I want it to write to the same file and not create a new one.

I tried to change the following code:

```
String outputFile = "../assets/test.xlsx";
List<int>? fileBytes = excel.save();

if (fileBytes != null) {
  File(join(outputFile))
    ..createSync(recursive: true)
    ..writeAsBytesSync(fileBytes);
}
```

to the following:

```
String outputFile = "../assets/test.xlsx";

File(outputFile)
  ..createSync(recursive: true)
  ..writeAsBytesSync(excel.encode()!);
}
```

In this case, it did not accomplish anything. It did not download nor did it write to the same file.